# Como verificar parênteses de uma expressão algébrica?

Tags: python-3.x

Estou tentando resolver um problema de um curso que estou fazendo porém não estou conseguindo imaginar um meio de resolver.

Preciso criar um programa onde o usuário digite uma expressão qualquer que use parênteses.

O meu aplicativo deverá analisar se a expressão passada está com os parênteses abertos e fechados na ordem correta, e não faço ideia de como fazer essa análise, poderiam me ajudar?

```
algebra = list()
aberto = fechado = 0
expressao = str(input('Digite sua expressão algébrica com parênteses: '))
if expressao == '(':
    aberto += 1
elif expressao == ')':
    fechado += 1
if aberto == fechado:
    algebra.append(expressao)
    print(f'A sua expressão {algebra} está correta!')
print(f'Sua expressão está incorreta, verifique seus parênteses {algebra}')
```

Comment: Já resolvi esse problema em C utilizando a notação polonesa reversa e uma pilha. Não sei se é a melhor solução, até porque a ideia quando fiz era resolver a expressão algébrica, mas é relativamente simples. Se for só para a verificação, possivelmente contar o número de parenteses abertos e fechados e comparar se é a mesma quantidade.

Comment: Veja esse projeto: https://github.com/hausen/exprtut. A idéia é shunting-yard algorithm para transfomar uma notaçao infixa em posfixa (notação polonesa reversa, RPN).

Comment: @WilliamJohnAdamTrindade então mas o que ele está fazendo no código dele é recebendo uma expressão infixa e criando uma pos, o que eu preciso é receber uma posfixa e verificar se a abertura de parênteses está correta. Eu fiz mais ou menos isso, porém ele fica mesmo assim sempre dando como válida veja o código que vou por na pergunta.

Comment: Uma expressão qualquer ou realmente uma expressão algébrica? Seu texto e seu título dizem informações contraditórias. Por exemplo, `(a + b (/c))` não é algébrico, mas respeita a fórmula de parênteses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def testaparenteses(expr):
    contador = 0
    for c in expr:
        if c == '(':
            contador += 1
        if c == ')':
            if contador > 0:
                contador -= 1
            else:
                return False

    return contador == 0

expressao = 'pi*(Rexterno**2 - Rinterno**2)'
print(testaparenteses(expressao))

expressao = '(x + (y + 1))*(x - (y + 1))'
print(testaparenteses(expressao))

expressao = ')(' # cagado
print(testaparenteses(expressao))

expressao = '(x + 7)**2 = x**2 + 14*x + 49)' # cagado
print(testaparenteses(expressao))
```

Comment: A pilha é desnecessária se não misturar tipos de parênteses. Basta um contador. Nesse caso, o autômato de pilha armazenaria um número em unário, daí incrementar seria empilhar, e decrementar seria desempilhar. Para ser válido, o contador seria vazio e também não poderia fechar algo que não abriu, o equivalente a seu segundo `if`

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado, entendi. Editei de acordo.

Comment: @MarceloUchimura obrigado

Comment: Obrigado ao @JeffersonQuesado pela sugestão, senão meu código ficaria um trambolho.

Comment: Não consigo deixar de comentar no facto de continuar a responder perguntas só com código. Sem uma única palavra a descrever nada. A comunidade como um todo ganharia  muito mais se descrevesse como aborda o problema e como o resolve, ao invés de entregar o código encomendado como quem entrega um bolo.

Answer (score -2):

conta = list()

conta.append(str(input('Digite uma conta que contenha parênteses: ')))

aberto = fechado = 0

for expressao in conta:

```
for elemento in expressao:
    if elemento == '(':
        aberto += 1
    elif elemento == ')':
        fechado += 1
```

if aberto == fechado:

```
print('Sua expressão está com o número certo de parênteses!')
```

else:

```
print('Sua expressão está com número incorreto de parênteses!')
```